# Hide Python Login API process

Tags: python

i execute Broker module to get LIVE price stock, when i receive data the command shell show all process

```
2021-12-24 11:43:01 - INFO - XTBApi.api.Client - CMD: get symbol AMD.US_4...

2021-12-24 11:43:01 - DEBUG - XTBApi.api.Client - took 0.01260685920715332 s.

2021-12-24 11:43:02 - INFO - XTBApi.api.Client - CMD: done

Thu Dec 23 21:59:58 CET 2021 ASK: AMD 146.9 $

Thu Dec 23 21:59:58 CET 2021 BID: AMD 146.52 $
```

how can i print only what i want to print ? how can i hide login process and just show price line?

Comment: What is the output format? json? xlm? Please post the exact output as you see it in terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most python packages that output things to the terminal without a specific print statement are using logging to do so. As for the first few lines, the logging outputs are labeled as INFO, DEBUG, and then INFO again.

To change the global logging level to ignore info and debug, try the following.

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/c/python+set+global+logging+level

By setting the logger to a higher level, small outputs such as those are hidden. You can also modify the source code packages even though that’s typically taboo.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to hide all Python logging scripts from terminal :

```
> import logging 
> logger = logging.getLogger('title of line what i want to hide ') 
>logger.propagate = False
```

That was perfect.
Thanks